# Luhn Algorithm Implementation into original code

Tags: javascript, luhn

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Credit Card Number Validator</title>
<style>
  <!-- .title {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: oblique;
    color: #006600;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: #FFFFE8;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  
  table {
    margin: auto;
    width: 600px;
  }
  
  .right {
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  .center {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #id {
    width: 175px;
  }
  
  -->
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="title">Validate a credit card number </p>
  <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td width="219" class="right">Enter the credit card number:</td>
        <td width="168" class="center"><input name="textfield" type="text" id="card"></td>
        <td width="196" id="output">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center"><input type="button" id="button" value="Test the Card Number!"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', credit, false);

    function credit() {
      data = document.getElementById("card").value;
      if (data) {
        cardnum = data.replace(/[^0-9]/, "");
      } else {
        alert('Please enter a number to test.');
      }
      if (cardnum.length == 16 && cardnum.charAt(0) == "5" && cardnum.charAt(1) != "0" && cardnum.charAt(12) == "7") {
        donecard = +cardnum.substr(0, 3) + " ";
        document.getElementById("card").innerHTML = donecard;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "valid";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "invalid";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to implement the Luhn algorithm to my code, so that it works together.
My first block works well it validates numbers correctly based off the code. This block works correctly. I want to implement the second part to it, which is the luhn algorithim with a loop or loops. What would be the best way to do this.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to implement the second part yet?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have but am stuck on it. I don't know if adding another function is the best route or just adding a loop to the function I have currently.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. Typed from my phone so probably has typos.

```
let sum = 0;
let len = cardnum.length;
for(let i=0; i = len; i++) { 
    let foo = cardnum.charAt(len-i) 
    if(i % 2 ) {
        foo = foo * 2;
        foo = (foo) > 9) ? foo-9 : foo;
        sum = sum + foo;
    } else {
        sum = sum + foo
}
if( (sum * 9) % 10 === 0) {
    console.log(‘valid’)
}
```

Comment: thanks! I guess my problem is how would I insert the algorithm into the code, I already have.